# Duda con bucle For

Tags: python-3.x, bucle-for

Estoy empezando con el tema de bucles, específicamente con el bucle For y tengo una duda, yo al escribir este código:

```
     lista = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
     index = 0
     for i in lista:
         lista[index] *= 10     
         print(lista)
```

Me devuelve esto:

```
[90000000000, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Disculpen mi ignorancia, estoy empezando a manejar bucles y me confunde el hecho de que se multiplique tantas veces sin razón aparente, digo sin razón ya que solo le asigne que se multiplicara por 10, aunque si lo hace no lo se por que varias veces, al principio pensé que seria como un bucle infinito pero creo que no lo es ya que me devuelve algo en la pantalla.

Comment: Se multiplica x10 en cada iteracion y cómo la lista tiene 10 eleemtos de multiplica en cada una de esa iteracion, la **i** es cada elemto si haces un ```print(i)``` verás cada elelmto para que cada elemento se multiplique por 10 solo cambia la variable ```index``` por ```i``` ya que *index* siempre será 0

Comment: entonces cuenta cuantos valores hay en la lista y entorno a eso lo multiplica por 10 si mal no entiendo no?

Comment: No cuenta los valores, si no que repite el ciclo por cada valor que este en la lista

Comment: @christian i tiene de valor el elemento de la lista. Por ejemplo en el primer ciclo, i=9, en el segundo i=8, etc

Comment: Por lo que al reemplazar i por index NO va a multiplicar cada elemento de la lista por 10

Comment: perfecto, ahora ya entiendo mejor, ya que hice la prueba antes eliminando algunos elementos de la lista y me devolvía con un menor tamaño

Comment: @Dante S. Lo siento me había olvidado, para que eso sea verdad se tendría que añadir el ```range(len(lista))```  puedo disculpas por el error

Comment: No hay problema, todos nos equivocamos a veces c:

Comment: No importa, lo que importa es que mi duda ya se soluciono :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asi funciona el código: primero pones `index` a cero, que se supone usaras después para recorrer una lista.

```
 index = 0
```

La expresión `for i in lista` significa que la variable `i` tomara sucesivamente los valores 9, 8, 7, ...

```
 for i in lista:
```

En cada iteración actualizas el valor de `lista[index]` multiplicandolo por 10. El detalle está en que nunca cambias el valor de `index`, y siempre vuelves a multiplicar el primer elemento, una y otra vez.

```
     lista[index] *= 10
```

Finalmente, este `print` debería estar un poco más a la izquierda.

```
     print(lista)
```

**Posible solución**

No está claro cual es el propósito de tu código, pero si deseas multiplicar cada elemento de la lista por 10, está es la manera de hacerlo:

```
lista = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
index = 0
for i in range(len(lista)):
    lista[i] *= 10
print(lista)
```

Comment: Estaba recién empezando a entender el Tema del "i" en el bucle for, ahora entiendo lo que hace en este bucle, y  lo de print al escribir esto se me fue un poco a la derecha pero en el código real lo tengo bien a la izquierda...

Comment: Aunque es un poco pronto para que uses comprensión de listas si estás empezando a entender los bucles `for`, este es un ejemplo muy bueno (por lo sencillo que es), para ver como funciona. Todo el código se puede reducir a `print([numero*10 for numero in lista])`.

Answer (score 0):

como te han mencionado los de mas dev para que puedas entender y no desanimarte debemos saber como funciona la estructura del bucle for en Python su sintaxis básica es así.

```
# indice_de_la_lista es la posición del elemento de la lista 
# Ej.: lista = [1,2,3], el elemento 1 de la lista corresponde al índice 0 seria así
# lista[0] mostraría 1

for indice_de_la_lista in lista:

    # Código a ejecutar
```

Ejemplo, con tu código:

```
tabla_de_multiplicar = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
index = 0
for i in tabla_de_multiplicar:
    tabla_de_multiplicar[index] *= 10
    
    index +=1 # debemos incrementar para leer cada elemento de nuestra lista.

print(tabla_de_multiplicar)
```

Bueno eso seria espero y me haya explicado bien, ojala en mis tiempos hubiesen existido estos foros me hubiese demorado menos en aprende, saludos a todos.